# Printing a web page in A4 format

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a long page of text that spans approximately 4 or 5 A4 pages. When I print it in Google Chrome, I want an image to be positioned exactly at the top of each page and another image to be positioned exactly at the bottom of each page (e.g., each image with a height of three centimeters), while the text between these two images should have a distance of 4 centimeters from the top and 4 centimeters from the bottom of each page when printed. I have written the following code so far, but the text appears below the images regardless of their positions, causing some of the text to be cut off and not printed. In other words, the text is not respecting the top and bottom margins. How can I resolve this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A4 Printable Page</title>
    <style>
        @media print {
            @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .header,
            .footer {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                color: #ffffff;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #000000;
            }

            .header {
                top: 0;
            }

            .footer {
                bottom: 0;
            }

            .header img,
            .footer img {
                height: auto;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .content {
                direction: rtl;
                padding-top: 4cm;
                margin-bottom: 4cm;
                margin-right: 2cm;
                margin-left: 2cm;
                page-break-after: always;
            }


        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="/img/prints/header.png" alt="Header Image">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        @for($i=1;$i<=115;$i++)
        <p>Text {{$i}}</p>
        @endfor
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <img src="/img/prints/footer.png" alt="Footer Image">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```